# Change input based on Jquery toggle

Tags: jquery, html

So basically, when I hit save, the var `name` should become the new text I entered in the input box, not the original name.

However, right now, no matter what I enter, it reverts it back to the original value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.edit-name').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').find('span,input').toggle();
  });
  var name = $('#name').val();
  $('#submit').on('click', function() {
    $('#result').html(name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="submit">Save</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<div class="editable">
  <span>John</span>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="John" style="display:none;" />
  <i class="edit-name">Edit</i>
</div>
```

Comment: All of you answered correctly, I can't believe I missed that. Yikes.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `name` var is initialized on document ready.
So it has the initial value of your input (Here John).
It should be declared into the click context.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit-name').on('click', function() {
      $(this).closest('div').find('span,input').toggle();
    });
    $('#submit').on('click', function() {
      var name = $('#name').val();
      $('#result').html(name);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="submit">Save</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<div class="editable">
  <span>John</span>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="John" style="display:none;" />
  <i class="edit-name">Edit</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the `name` variable before any changes are made. This value is never updated after you make a change.

You need to move the name variable inside the event handler

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.edit-name').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').find('span,input').toggle();
  });
  $('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    $('#result').html(name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="submit">Save</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<div class="editable">
  <span>John</span>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="John" style="display:none;" />
  <i class="edit-name">Edit</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read input again and set it to `name` variable on click of save button. see below code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.edit-name').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').find('span,input').toggle();
  });
  var name = $('#name').val();
  $('#submit').on('click', function() {
    $('.edit-name').click();//toggle input and span
    name = $('#name').val();
    $(".editable span").text(name);
    $('#result').html(name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="submit">Save</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<div class="editable">
  <span>John</span>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="John" style="display:none;" />
  <i class="edit-name">Edit</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you have already stored the result in variable `name`, What you could do is cache the element and then grab the value from it in the click handler

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.edit-name').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').find('span,input').toggle();
  });
  var name = $('#name'); // Here you cache the element
  $('#submit').on('click', function() {
    $('#result').html(name.val()); // call val () the element
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="submit">Save</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<div class="editable">
  <span>John</span>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="John" style="display:none;" />
  <i class="edit-name">Edit</i>
</div>
```